# Batch File/Script Delete every 3 files in a directory

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with sequentially named images (a0001, a0002, a0003, etc.) and I was wondering if there was a way to delete every 3 files without touching the others.

So for example, I have: a0001, a0002, a0003, a0004, a0005 a0006, a0007, a0008, a0009

And after I would like to have: a0001, a0005, a0009

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the syntax, as I usualy don't write batch scripts, but should be something like:

```
set z = 0
for /f %%a IN (‘dir /b *’) do {
  set z = z + 1;
  if (z % 3 == 0) del %%a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vbscript you can use

```
strFolder = WScript.Arguments(0)
Set objFS = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)
i=0
For Each strFile In objFolder.Files
    If i Mod 4 <> 0 Then
        WScript.Echo strFile.Name
        objFS.DeleteFile(strFile.Name)
    End If
    i=i+1
Next
```

usage:

```
C:\test> cscript //nologo test.vbs c:\folder_to_process
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution.  This allows you to specify what to delete (eg `c:\temp\*.tmp`) how many files to skip (the default being `3` as you requested) and what order to use (the default being `n` - filename).  You can use any DIR ordering eg `N` (name) or `ES` (extension then size), see `dir /?` to learn more about ordering.  You shouldn't start the order command with `/o` (unlike dir) - it's auto-prepended.

**Source:** ndel.bat

```
@echo off
::: ndel - Deletes every nth file matching the spec
::: syntax: ndel.bat FILESPEC [skipcount] [sortorder]
:::           FILESPEC  - Files to be searched through
:::           skipcount - number of files to skip (optional - default 3)
:::           sortorder - File order (see: DIR for options - default N (name))

:: With no arguments show the above usage text
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^:::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
set find=%1
set evry=4
set ord=n
if "%~2" neq "" set /a evry=(%2+1)
if "%~3" neq "" set ord=%3

set count=0
for /f %%f IN ('dir %find% /b /o%%ord%%') do (
    call :test_file "%%f"
)
GOTO:eof

:test_file
set /a _r="%count% %% %evry%"
if %_r%==0 echo %1
::-to delete- if %_r%==0 del %1
set /a count+=1
GOTO:eof
```

**Notes:**

- You need to comment out `if %_r%==0 echo %1` and remove the starting comment `::-to delete-` to actually preform the delete (once you're happy it works :)).
- The first few lines just output usage if you type in `ndel` (without a parameter)
- Skip three is the same as saying delete every fourth file, which is why `evry` takes skip+1, and by default is set to 4 (skip 3).
- `filespec` can include a folder and complicated wild-card matches (just like `dir`).
- A subroutine has to be used to `count` properly through the `for` (Environment variables within a `FOR` loop are expanded at the beginning of the loop and won't change until *after* the end of the `DO` section)
- Calling `ndel c:\temp\*.tmp 0` is the same as `del c:\temp\*.tmp` (since skip 0 = all)